# Computation of the number of uppercase letters in a string

Tags: postgresql, text

I've bumped into a seemingly simple problem that I'm unable to solve. I would like to **determine whether the number of uppercase letters is greater than the number of lowercase letter** (ignoring special character, spaces etc).

Example

```
id | text        | upper_greater_lower | note
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Hello World | False               | because |HW| < |elloorld|
2  | The XYZ     | True                | because |TXYZ| > |he|
3  | Foo!!!      | False               | because |F| < |oo|
4  | BAr???      | True                | because |BA| > |r|
```

My initial idea was to determine the number of lowecase letters, then uppercase letters, and finally, compare them. However, I'm unable to do so in any elegant and efficient way.

I expect handling ~30M rows with ~300 character each.

What would you suggest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expression magic, that could be:

```
SELECT length(regexp_replace(textcol, '[^[:upper:]]', '', 'g'))
     > length(regexp_replace(textcol, '[^[:lower:]]', '', 'g'))
FROM atable;
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually doesn't work because string comparison is based on lexicographical sorting rather than on length. You have probably meant using `char_length(regexp_replace(...)) > char_length(regexp_replace(...)) `. That seems to both work and be very elegant. Also pretty slow, though. Thanks!

Comment: Uargh, sorry, fixed. About speed, yes, regular expressions are slow, but that works in general, no matter what "upper case character" and "lower case character" means in your locale. You can be faster if you - say - are happy with testing for ASCII characters only.